# AttributeError: type object 'HashStore' has no attribute 'hashtag' while using datastore in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

This is how my datastore looks like :

```
class HashStore(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual HashStore entry with hastag, tile, and date."""
    author = ndb.UserProperty()
    title = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    hastag = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False, default="")
    viewDate = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is how my request handler looks like :

```
class Add(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        NoteTitle = self.request.get("title")
        NoteHashtags = self.request.get("hashtags")

        HashEntry=HashStore(author=users.get_current_user(),hashtag=NoteHashtags,title=NoteTitle)
        HashEntry.put()
```

When I try to add data to datastore i keep getting this error :

```
type object 'HashStore' has no attribute 'hashtag'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~keep-tabs-on/1.371681382109791887/KeepTabsOn.py", line 55, in post
    HashEntry=HashStore(author=users.get_current_user(),hashtag=NoteHashtags,title=NoteTitle)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2745, in __init__
    self._set_attributes(kwds)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2788, in _set_attributes
    prop = getattr(cls, name)  # Raises AttributeError for unknown properties.
AttributeError: type object 'HashStore' has no attribute 'hashtag'
```

Can you guys point me to the right direction or what i'm missing here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like spelling error. The class attribute you have is spelled HASTAG not HASHTAG